# Simple name/content multipart/formdata http post using cURL and native Android NDK results in CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT

Tags: android, c, curl, android-ndk

Implementing an app that is partially native that uses cURL HTTP post to retrieve data based on the content of the the post payload.
The code is written in the C programming language. The Android native app targets:

```
compileSdkVersion = 23
minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
```

The sequence of cURL calls goes something like this:

```
curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, curlErrorBuf);
curl_formadd(&post, &last,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "version",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "1",
             CURLFORM_END);
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, SEARCH_POST_URL)
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, receiveHTTP)
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, NULL)
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post)
curl_easy_perform(curlHandle)
```

All return values are checked for call errors. The curl_easy_perform() call returns the only error:

```
ret == 43 (obviously != CURLE_OK),
curl_easy_strerror(returned value by curl_easy_perform()) == "Error",
curlErrorBuf, set by CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER option == ""
```

Documented cURL error: CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT, (43), "Internal error. A function was called with a bad parameter."

The same error results when using:

```
https and calling curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L)
or
http and not setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to 0L
```

I can get the http and https requests to complete successfully by simply not including one or more simple curl_formadd(CURLFORM_COPYNAME, CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS) calls (basically, by not adding one or more multipart/formdata fields to the http post request).

I'm beginning to think that the cURL post broke when I deployed to a phone device running Android 6.0.1 versus 5.1.1 (LOLLIPOP_MR1). I'm finding that curl calls fails on a Samsung phone running Android 6.0.1 (M) but works on a Nexus phone running 5.1.1 (LOLLIPOP_MR1). It seems to be related to when cURL is built for and deployed to a 64bit architecture device.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when running on arm64-v8a device architecture.
And the reason was, that I had curl_config.h with

```
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
```

which is obviously wrong for 64 bit.

My solution: add

```
GLOBAL_CFLAGS += -DARCH_$(subst -,_,$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
```

to Android.mk
and make conditional SIZEOF_SIZE_T define in curl_config.h:

```
#if defined(ARCH_arm64_v8a) || defined(ARCH_x86_64)
#   define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           8
#elif defined(ARCH_armeabi_v7a) || defined(ARCH_x86)
#   define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
#else
#   error "Can't detect 32/64 architechture: ARCH_<architechture> not defined."
#endif
```